# Write to Google Cloud storage bucket as if it were a directory?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've written a python script that resamples and renames a ton of audio data and moves it to a new location on disk. I'd like to use this script to move the data I'm resampling to a google storage bucket.

**Question:** Is there a way to connect/mount your GCP VM instance to a bucket in such a way that reading and writing can be done as if the bucket is just another directory?

For example, this is somewhere in my script:

```
# load audio from old location
audio, _ = librosa.load(old_path):

# Do some stuff to the audio
# ...

# write audio to new location
with sf.SoundFile(new_path, 'w', sr, channels=1, format='WAV') as f:
      f.write(audio)
```

I'd like to have a way to get the `path` to my bucket because my script takes an `old_path` where the original data is, resamples and moves it to a `new_path`.

My script would not be as simple to modify as the snippet above makes it seem, because I'm doing a lot of multiprocessing. Plus I'd like to make the script generic so I can re-use it for local files, etc. Basically, altering the script is off the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the FUSE adapter to mount your GCS bucket onto the local filesystem

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse

For Linux:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcsfuse
gcsfuse mybucket /my/path
```

Alternatively you could use the GCS Client for Python to upload your content directly:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [Cloud Storage FUSE.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) More info and some examples [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/README.md).

To mount a bucket using gcsfuse over an existing directory /path/to/mount, invoke it like this:

```
gcsfuse my-bucket /path/to/mount
```

I recommend having a bucket that is exclusively accessed through `gcsfuse` to keep things simple.

Important node: gcsfuse *It is distributed as-is, without warranties of any kind.*